# How to remove elements from a xml file based on the value of a sub element using ansible?

Tags: xml, ansible

I have multiple `item` elements like the following one inside a `/path/to/content/` element:

```
<item>
  <label>SOME_TEXT</label>
  <other_elements/>
</item>
```

Using ansible's `community.general.xml` module as follows allows me to remove all existing `item` elements:

```
- name: "Remove all items"
  become: true
  community.general.xml:
    path: "{{ path_to_my_xml_file }}"
    xpath: /path/to/content/*
    pretty_print: yes
    state: absent
```

How can I use the `community.general.xml` module of ansible to only remove an `item` who's `label`'s value (i.e. `SOME_TEXT`) matches a string `label_of_item_to_remove` ?

If it's not possible with `community.general.xml` what other module could be used to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: ***"Remove an item who's label's value (i.e. SOME_TEXT) matches a string label_of_item_to_remove"***

Yes. It is possible. For example, given the file

```xml
shell> cat /tmp/test.xml 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<doc>
<item>
  <label>SOME_TEXT</label>
  <other_elements/>
</item>
<item>
  <label>OTHER_TEXT</label>
  <other_elements/>
</item>
</doc>
```

the task below will remove the first item

```yaml
    - community.general.xml:
        path: /tmp/test.xml
        xpath: "/doc/item[label='{{ label_of_item_to_remove }}']"
        state: absent
      vars:
        label_of_item_to_remove: SOME_TEXT
```

Running the play with options *--check --diff* shows

```xml
TASK [community.general.xml] *********************************************
--- before
+++ after
@@ -1,9 +1,5 @@
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <doc>
-<item>
-  <label>SOME_TEXT</label>
-  <other_elements/>
-</item>
 <item>
   <label>OTHER_TEXT</label>
   <other_elements/>
```